# How many wired controllers fit on an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

How many wired controllers can fit on an Xbox 360? I've heard just 2, but other people say that there is another port in the back, and still others say that there is a hub that you can connect to an Xbox 360. What is the maximum number of wired controllers that you have been able to fit on your Xbox 360?

BTW, I have a new Xbox 360 250 GB if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7):

The Xbox 360, 250 GB S console has 5 standard USB 2.0 ports. Games like Rockband came with a USB hub that allowed more game controllers to be plugged in. The older models before June 2010 had 3 ports, two in the front and 1 in the back.

Most games are only going to be compatible with up to 4 controllers at most locally.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360

Comment: So, does that mean that I _can_ hook up 2 or more wired controllers?

Comment: Yes, you can connect up to five wired controllers. One for each USB port. Most games will use four or fewer.

Comment: Standard PC compliant USB hubs allow you to add more devices as well.  With daisy chaining, you can add a lot of hubs, and therefore, a large (albeit finite) number of USB devices.

Comment: Your only limits are either the USB specification limit (128 in USB 2.0 I think) or the limit in the Xbox 360 firmware (probably lower).

Comment: Using the Rockband USB Hub, which appeared to be nothing special, I've had 4 wired controllers active on a box, using the 2 front ports only.  3 off the hub, one off the native port.  Note that the hub required external power.